# Currency Exchange - How to call a function within a function from onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Stackers: I coded up a foreign exchange calculator (Indian Rupees to US Dollars) with additions for the Indian counting system of crore and lakh. It works well enough as you see here:  [Foreign Exchange Calculator][1] .

In order to improve it, I want to figure a way to have the code go out and grab a JSON object with today's exchange rate which is available via API in many places. While I can write a function that gets the exchange rate, I am having no luck getting an onclick call to make it work.

I looked at the jQuery page but couldn't find an answer to this. If I use the load function, the format is this:

```
$('selector').load('url',callback) {
    do some callback of some kind
};
```

With a simple page, I can get this to work each time, but -

Because I want to trigger the call for the latest exchange rate with an onclick html call, I want to use a function from the onclick. My first question is, what should my selector be? Normally I would direct it to innerHTML via an id or a class but this doesn't seem to work here.

Secondly, it would seem that I should set my code so that when the page loads, it goes out and notes the current exchange rate. Is there a way for JavaScript/jQuery to do this upon page load even if I haven't called on the function yet? Optimally, I would set the variable to today's rate once and save it locally so I only need to update once a day.

Finally, I have set the function call related to the onclick as:

```
onclick = run(123.45)   with 123.45 being today's rate.
```

is there a way to replace 123.45 with a function, so a function within a function? I want to use today's rate as returned from the jQuery `.load` method as the argument to populate the run function call. No matter how I try, I can't get it to work. I have searched google and haven't found anything which leads me to believe that I am going about this all wrong.

Thanks for any assistance.

```
// js logic to run calculator with the assumption that each 
// calculation involves some pos or negative number and then 
// an operator (+-/*) which always yields a positive number. 
// ex: 2 + 2 = (4 elements) adding another number and operator 
// ex: / 3.5 is now 6 elements in the array.

arr = [];
var total = 0, rupee;
var box = document.getElementById("display");
```

//jquery call for current Rupee to USD exhcange rate

```
var url = "https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD";

// BELOW IS THE CODE FROM MY FIRST QUESTION
$(**WHATSHOULDTHISSELECTORBE?**).load(url, function(responseTxt) {
   var obj = JSON.parse(responseTxt);
   rupee = obj.rates.INR;
 });
```

// end of rupee to dollar call

```
function run(digit) {
  x = box.value;
  if (x !== '.' && isNaN(x)) {
    box.value = "";
  }
  box.value += digit;
}

function runPlus() {
  var digits = box.value;
  if (digits === "") {
    return;
  }
  arr.push(Number(digits)); // tried parseInt but dropped decimal nos.

  box.value += "+";
  arr.push("+");
  console.log(arr);
}

function runMinus() {
   var digits = box.value;
  if (digits === '') {
    arr.push("-");
    return;
  }
  arr.push(Number(digits));
  box.value = "";
  box.value = "-";
  arr.push("-");
  console.log(arr);
}

function runMult() {
  var digits = box.value;
  if (digits === "") {
    return;
  }
  arr.push(Number(digits));
  box.value = "";
  box.value += "*";
  arr.push("*");
  console.log(arr);
}

function runDiv() {
  var digits = box.value;
  if (digits === "") {
    return;
  }
  arr.push(Number(digits));
  box.value = "";
  box.value += "/";
  arr.push("/");
  console.log(arr);
}

function runEquals() {
  var digits = box.value;
   if (digits === "") {
    return;
  }
  arr.push(Number(digits));
  arr.push("=");

  box.value = "";
  total = arr[0];
  var ans = calculateArr(arr);
  box.value = ans;
}

  function runClear() {
  box.value = "";
arr = [];
}

function calculateArr(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 2) {

  if (arr[i + 1] === "+") {
   total = total + arr[i + 2];

} else if (arr[i + 1] === "-") {
  total = total - arr[i + 2];

} else if (arr[i + 1] === "*") {
  total = total * arr[i + 2];

} else if (arr[i + 1] === "/") {
  total = total / arr[i + 2];

} else if (arr[i + 1] === "=") {
  total = total;

} else alert("Error");

}
  return ReplaceNumberWithCommas(total);
}

function ReplaceNumberWithCommas(yourNumber) {
  //Seperates the components of the number
  var n = yourNumber.toString().split(".");
  //Comma-fies the first part
  n[0] = n[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  //Combines the two sections
  if (n[1]) {
    n[1] = n[1].split("").slice(0, 2);
    n[1] = n[1].join("");
  }
  return n.join(".");
}




  [1]: http://codepen.io/Qstreet/pen/GovZdg
```

Comment: I made a small fiddle on your case. Does this answer your question about functions within a function? https://jsfiddle.net/tz269sog/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much @Anmol. I got it working with this:

```
var url = "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD";

function runRup() {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET",url,false);
xhr.send(null);
var rt = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
return rt.rates.INR;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to retrieve values automatically on page load , you need to use xhr request.

```
$.get( "your-url", function( data ) {
$( "where you want to insert it" ).html( data );
//or call your-custom-function(data);
});
```

If you want to fetch values upon click event , insert above code as a function to jquery click event handler